VirtualBox 7 - How to enable "shift + Numpad:Delete" shortcut with Numlock enable?
The "shift + Numpad:Delete" shortcut is not working in my VirtualBox 7.
At first I thought the problem was the Windows 10 ISO I was using, but I also tried the exact same ISO and configuration in VMware and the shortcut worked. I also tried removing all hotkeys in "Input > Keyboard > Keyboard Settings" but with no results.
Does anyone know how to make the “shift + Numpad:Delete” shortcut work with Numlock enable in a VirtualBox 7?
